# return object if list<object> value is exists (Javascript, jquery grep/map)

Tags: javascript, jquery, list

I'm using grep and map functions to get the object if the value is exists in the list, but it does not work well.

I have a list customList and the customObject has the int id property and List value properties.

```
customobject[0].id
customObject[0].value[]
```

What I want is check if in the List the value 5 exists.

The function what I'm using is:

```
var gettedcustomObject = $.grep(customList, function (e) {
    var result = e.Value.map(function (a) { return a === 5;});
    return result;
});
```

What am I doing wrong and what is the correct implementation?

Note: 2x foreach could be a solution, but customList has more than 1000 objects with 10000 values. I think that slow down the proces.

Comment: `Note: 2x foreach could be a solution, but customList has more than 1000 objects with 10000 values!. I think that slow down the proces.` What do you think `grep` and `map` are going to do? You can't loop a list without looping a list.

Comment: *"Note: 2x foreach could be a solution, but customList has more than 1000 objects with 10000 values!. I think that slow down the proces."* What do you think `$.grep` and `Array#map` do that isn't the same as looping through things?

Comment: @MattBurland: LOL

Comment: *"but it does not work well."* does not work well? Or does not work at all? What does it do? What is it supposed to do? How do they differ?

Comment: @MattBurland the code returns a true if the value exists and a false if doesn't. But what i want is to return the object.

Comment: @E75: Then use [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it.

```
var gettedcustomObject = customList.filter(function(v){
    var ln = v.Value.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < ln; i++){
       if(v.Value[i] == 5){
           return true;
       }
    }
    return false;
    // Or simply:
    // return v.Value.indexOf(5) != -1;
});
```

This will work if `v.Value` is an array.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder That is a good point. I will change my answer to make it more efficient.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder the question is clear enough. The code what i have returns a true or a false, not the object!

Answer (score 0):

You should look at `some`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some#Polyfill

Way faster than the other methods like `filter`, `map` or `sort` as it was designed for this.

```js
//List to work against
var arr = [];
//Populate
while (arr.length < 9999999) {
  arr.push(Math.random() * 999999)
}
//Set element to find
arr[10] = "test";

//Begin timing
var d = new Date().getTime();
//Run filter
console.log(arr.filter(function(a){return a === "test"}).length > 0);
//How long did it take
console.log("`filter` took:",new Date().getTime() - d,"ms")

//Begin timing
d = new Date().getTime();
//Run filter
console.log(arr.some(function(a){return a === "test"}));
//How long did it take
console.log("`some` took:",new Date().getTime() - d,"ms")
```

```html
<script>
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some#Polyfill
// Production steps of ECMA-262, Edition 5, 15.4.4.17
// Reference: http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.17
if (!Array.prototype.some) {
  Array.prototype.some = function(fun/*, thisArg*/) {
    'use strict';

    if (this == null) {
      throw new TypeError('Array.prototype.some called on null or undefined');
    }

    if (typeof fun !== 'function') {
      throw new TypeError();
    }

    var t = Object(this);
    var len = t.length >>> 0;

    var thisArg = arguments.length >= 2 ? arguments[1] : void 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      if (i in t && fun.call(thisArg, t[i], i, t)) {
        return true;
      }
    }

    return false;
  };
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to find the first object in the list that contains `5` in the `Value` property, then you're looking for `Array#find` and `Array#indexOf`:

```
var gettedcustomObject = customList.find(function(entry) {
    return entry.Value.indexOf(5) != -1;
});
```

Note that `Array#find` was added relatively recently and so you may need a polyfill for it (which is trivial). [MDN has one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

Or you could use [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) instead of `indexOf`, which will be in ES2017 and is also polyfillable:

```
var gettedcustomObject = customList.find(function(entry) {
    return entry.Value.includes(5);
});
```

Live Example (using `indexOf`):

```js
var customList = [
  {
    note: "I'm not a match",
    Value: [2, 3, 4]
  },
  {
    note: "I'm not a match either",
    Value: [78, 4, 27]
  },
  {
    note: "I'm a match",
    Value: [889, 5, 27]
  },
  {
    note: "I'm also a match, but you won't find me",
    Value: [4, 6, 5]
  }
];
var gettedcustomObject = customList.find(function(entry) {
  return entry.Value.indexOf(5) != -1;
});
console.log(gettedcustomObject);
```

If your logic matching the item inside `Value` were more complicated, you'd use `Array#some` and a callback function rathe than `indexOf`. But when looking to see if an array for an entry in an array based on `===`, `indexOf` or the new `Array#includes` are the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

one approach using Array.some() and Array.indexOf(). some loop break once the element is found

```
var gettedcustomObject;

customobject.some(function(obj){
  if(obj.value.indexOf(5) >-1){
    gettedcustomObject = obj;
    return true;
  }
});
```